# Why I am getting the error called “too much input”?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I need to write a program which read sentence backward:

```
Line: This is an example line of text. (input 1)
.txet fo enil elpmaxe na si sihT (Output 2)
Line: HeLLo ThErE! (input 2)
!ErEhT oLLeH (Output 2)
```

The code below is giving me the required output:

```
n = input("Line: ")
for i in range(len(n)-1,-1,-1):
  print(n[i], end="")
n = input("\nLine: ")
for j in range(len(n)-1,-1,-1):
  print(n[j], end="")
```

However, the compilor is showing an error - Your submission attempted to read too much input! This occurred on line 4 of your submission.

Please help.

Comment: It also mentions the explaination of the error as below - Often this means that one of your loops ran for more iterations than it was meant to. You should test your program some more and make sure that it stops asking for input after the correct number of iterations.

Comment: Perhaps whatever calls the code you provided has the issue because this code works fine for me.  I tried to break it but it seems to be holding up nicely.  Please cut/paste the actual error produced by the interpreter so we can have a look at that.